# Handling expired token web page

Tags: reactjs, mern

This question might be to simple for you but I am confused. I issued a token created from JWT to reset password using React JS and NodeJS (express). I want to expire a token based web page, how can I do that?

UPDATE: For someone who is looking at this, just add expiresIn function to the properties of token, and it will work. And keep this for very small time.

Comment: I think this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265307/13566428

Comment: Creating a database doesn't seem like a long-term option. Especially, if its only job is to match the previously used tokens. There must be a different way. Thanks for replying, though.

Comment: I was referring to this answer: "Use the user's current password's hash for signing the JWT token, in this way all tokens generated before a successful password change would get invalidated the next time. I got the idea from here https://www.jbspeakr.cc/howto-single-use-jwt/."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generating the token, you should set a parameter that define max-usage. Add a middleware that checks for the usage and increments it for every API-request (ensure public assets like CSS/JS are ignored). And for this case, when the counter ticks beyond-1,  expire the token.
Are you looking for anything more specific, like a code reference?

Comment: I like this but I am new in coding completely. So a code reference or any documents will help me.